# Return Date Type

Tags: android, eclipse, date, casting, calendar

I have this code:

```
    private Date validarFecha(Date fecha)
    {
       int dia = dpFecha.getDayOfMonth();
       int mes = dpFecha.getMonth();
       int año =  dpFecha.getYear();

       Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendario.set(dia, mes, año);

       final Calendar hoy = Calendar.getInstance();

       if(calendario == hoy | calendario == null)
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Verifica la fecha seleccionada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else
       {
          //Here I need to return calendario
       }
    }
```

What can i do to cast the Calendar type of "calendario" into a Date type so I can return it?
I have tried a lot of code that I've searched but but nothing works D:

Comment: No need to cast `calendario` to `Date`. call `calendario.getTime()` which will return Date object from `calendario`

Comment: Use calendario.getTime() to return Date object from Calendar instance.

Comment: If you want to use Calendar object back there, you must change the return type you defined in the method to "Calendar" ....

Answer (score 1):

```
 else
 {
    //Here I need to return calendario
    return calendario.getTime();    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use

```
calendario.getTime();
```

This method is odly named, in that it actually returns a `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can chage the return type to Calander

```
private Calendar validarFecha(Date fecha) {
    // Do whatever you want
    return calendario;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will give you the date object.

```
else {

    //Here I need to return calendario
    return calendario.getTime();         
}
```